# Make an SQL query to count

Tags: sql

I have made a sql database and need to make a query to count.

I need to: Count (not list) the grades (“A” ‐ “F”) given by each professor

This data is comming from two tables.

Table one: (DW_Course_facts): has periodKey, courseKey, studentKey, profKey, and grade.

Table two: (DW_Professor): has profKey, profID, name, title, deptID, and deptName.

What would this query look like?

Comment: Can you provide an example by using sqlfiddle.net ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? We're not here to do your homework for you. :-)

Comment: Yes, I have tried it myself.  I have many of these querys to do.  Once I get an idea of one it would help with the rest.

Comment: It might be worth your while to learn some fundamentals before trying to do stuff.  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: @mattytommo, why is it relevant whether or not it's homework?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT p.Name FROM tableTwo p WHERE p.profKey=g.profKey) As ProfName,
    g.grade,
    COUNT(g.grade) As gradeCount
FROM  tableOne g
GROUP BY profKey, grade
ORDER BY profKey, grade
```

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick fiddle showing how you could do it.

SQLFiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4a55/4